# Using Accelerate (CLAPACK) to solve a compressed-column-storage matrix (in xcode)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, matrix, lapack

Does anyone know what function/method to use in Accelerate (CLAPACK) to solve an compressed-column-storage  matrix(ccs).I'm looking for any sample code, links to samples, hints on how to solve the matrix. I've been looking through the documentation but most everything has to do with more complex graphical systems and there are hundreds of seemingly similar methods.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

LAPACK does not have support for sparse matrix layouts.

Are you wedded to the ccs storage layout?  How big is your matrix?

Comment: hi stephen.i solved it by convert matrix from ccs to coordinate matrix and using Lapack